# Display SignIn Modal in topbar menu with zurb foundation 5 and meteor

Tags: meteor, navigation, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5, accounts

I am working on a project with Meteor JS (version 1.2) using the [accounts-password package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-password) for user sign up / sign in.

I am using - or at least try to use - Zurb Foundation 5 (version 5.3) for my projekt. I tested the [ewall:foundation package](https://atmospherejs.com/ewall/foundation) and the [juliancwirko:zf5 package](https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/zf5) and both works well.

For accounts i added the [useraccounts:foundation package](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/foundation).

Using the [{{> atForm}} tamplate](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#templates) on a page works also well. The SignIn/SignUp Form displays correctly.

But using it in a fixed top NavBar does not work. It displays it not correctly. (See pictures and source below.)

I am getting NO errors in the console that something is not loading correctly.

I assume the useraccounts:foundation package to display a button/link in the navbar and then show a modal/popup with the login form.

**My Question:** Is any of the packages broken or am I using them wrong in any way?

Or is my assumption, that the useraccounts:foundation package should display the signin form in a nav bar with a modal, just wrong? If so, what do I need to do to get that desired behavior in my app?

[image: Meteor demo app with Foundation5 and useraccounts-foundation]
The App displays the signin form in the page correctly, but in the navbar wrong.

[image: Same App with mobile view...]
In the mobile view ...

[image: ... displays it also not correct]
... it displays also not correctly.

I made a simple projekt without any router etc to test just the above packages, here is the source:

**project/client/main.html**

```
<head>
    <title>ZF5 Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> header}}

    {{> content}}
</body>
```

**project/client/header.html**

```
<template name="header">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
        <ul class="title-area">

            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">ZF5 Demo</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section style="left: 0%;" class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>{{> atForm}}</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</template>
```

**project/client/header.js**

```
Template.header.rendered = function () {
    $(document).foundation('reflow');
}
```

**project/client/content.js**

```
<template name="content">
    <section class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="panel">
                <h1>Content</h1>

                {{> atForm}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

The rendered HTML looks like that (only the navbar part).

```
<body>
<nav data-topbar="" class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">

            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">ZF5 Demo</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section" style="left: 0%;">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
    <div class="at-form">

        <div class="at-title">
    <h3>Sign In</h3>
  </div>
        <div class="at-pwd-form">
    <form method="POST" action="#" novalidate="" id="at-pwd-form" role="form">
    <div class="at-input row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">

        <label for="at-field-email">
          Email 
        </label>

      <input aria-label="Email " placeholder="Email" name="at-field-email" id="at-field-email" type="email">

    </div>
  </div>    
    <div class="at-input row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">

        <label for="at-field-password">
          Password 
        </label>

      <input aria-label="Password " placeholder="Password" name="at-field-password" id="at-field-password" type="password">

    </div>
  </div>    
      <button id="at-btn" class="at-btn button" type="submit">
    Sign In
  </button>
    </form>
  </div>
        <div class="at-signup-link">
    <p>
      Don't have an account?
      <a class="at-link at-signup" id="at-signUp" href="#">Register</a>

    </p>
  </div>
    </div>
  </li>
            </ul>
        </section></nav>
[...content...]</body>
```

**EDIT**

I tried to wrap the {{> atForm}} template into a dropdown in  **project/client/header.html**:

```
<template name="header">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
        <ul class="title-area">

            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">ZF5 Demo</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section style="left: 0%;" class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                <li>
                    <a data-dropdown="signin-dropdown" aria-controls="signin-dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Sign In</a>
                    <div id="signin-dropdown" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div>
                            {{> atForm}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</template>
```

The result looks like this:

[image: LogIn Dropdown] Now the Menu Button looks better, ...

[image: LogIn Dropdown open] ... but the LogIn Form is rendered incorrect.

I also tried out several other things and nothing worked out.

I think this is a problem only with the way I use foundation, because I am new to that framework and don't understand every detail.

So I will stick with the SignIn Modal Form like shown in that [example](http://zurb.com/building-blocks/navigation-with-login).

Comment: Is this more than a css problem?

Comment: I don't know. I suppose that the {{>atForm}} template renders the login form as a button that opens a modal/dropdown. Maybe its just a CSS/HTML problem, that i need to wrap the form with some tags? But I am not sure which I should use. I tried also to wrap it as a Dropdown, but it does not work either. I will update my question with that result.